# Extract wildcard key in Bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure in bigquery,

| id | desc |
| --- | --- |
| btjap | {"val":{"60fc-4955-8d9b":{"key":"top"},"4f96-4c9e-88f0":{"key":"left"}}} |
| fxlol | {"val":{"c783-9342-h73s":{"key":"up"},"83hs-eudu-s839":{"key":"above"}, "37s9-dh3u-39sr":{"key":"right"}}} |
| nretx | {"val":{}} |

The desc column contains multiple wildcard keys as value for the **val** key .

I want to unpack the data into the following table

| id | code | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| btjap | 60fc-4955-8d9b | top |
| btjap | 4f96-4c9e-88f0 | left |
| fxlol | c783-9342-h73s | up |
| fxlol | 83hs-eudu-s839 | above |
| fxlol | 37s9-dh3u-39sr | right |
| nretx |  |  |

any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @SelVazi's answer, but you can use UDFs as well and need to `LEFT JOIN` flattened arrays for your expected result.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION keys(json STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRING> LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(json));
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION values(json STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRING> LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(json)).map(e => e.key);
""";


WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'btjap' id, '{"val":{"60fc-4955-8d9b":{"key":"top"},"4f96-4c9e-88f0":{"key":"left"}}}' `desc` UNION ALL
  SELECT 'fxlol', '{"val":{"c783-9342-h73s":{"key":"up"},"83hs-eudu-s839":{"key":"above"}, "37s9-dh3u-39sr":{"key":"right"}}}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'nretx', '{"val":{}}'
)
SELECT id, code, key
  FROM sample_table
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(keys(JSON_QUERY(`desc`, '$.val'))) code WITH offset
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(values(JSON_QUERY(`desc`, '$.val'))) key WITH offset USING (offset);
```

**query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `json_extract_keys` to extract keys (code) from the json, then to access to the nested elements we can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

```
with mytable as (
  select 'btjap' as id,     '{"val":{"60fc-4955-8d9b":{"key":"top"},"4f96-4c9e-88f0":{"key":"left"}}}' as descr union all
  select 'fxlol',   '{"val":{"c783-9342-h73s":{"key":"up"},"83hs-eudu-s839":{"key":"above"}, "37s9-dh3u-39sr":{"key":"right"}}}' union all
  select 'nretx',   '{"val":{}}'
)
select id, code, REGEXP_EXTRACT(descr, FORMAT('"%s":{"key":"([a-z1-9]*)".*', code)) key
from mytable t,
UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys(JSON_QUERY(t.descr, '$.val'))) as code;
```

In case the function `json_extract_keys` is not found in your location then you can create an equivalent UDF :

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_extract_keys(json STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRING> LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    return Object.keys(JSON.parse(json));
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
""";

with mytable as (
  select 'btjap' as id,     '{"val":{"60fc-4955-8d9b":{"key":"top"},"4f96-4c9e-88f0":{"key":"left"}}}' as descr union all
  select 'fxlol',   '{"val":{"c783-9342-h73s":{"key":"up"},"83hs-eudu-s839":{"key":"above"}, "37s9-dh3u-39sr":{"key":"right"}}}' union all
  select 'nretx',   '{"val":{}}'
)
select id, code, REGEXP_EXTRACT(descr, FORMAT('"%s":{"key":"([a-z1-9]*)".*', code)) key
from mytable t,
UNNEST(json_extract_keys(JSON_QUERY(t.descr, '$.val'))) as code;
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find information about the function **bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys**. When I use this function I get an error _Not found: Dataset  was not found in location US_

Comment: I have edited my question to handle the case where `json_extract_keys` is not found

Comment: Thank you, I am able to use the function. I could get the `code` but not the `key`. I get a null value for the key. It seems the **FORMAT** is not working for my data which is been dumped into bigquery. Is there any other way to extract the `key`?

Comment: Could share some of the data returning null ?